# Topology problem around concave edges

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, unity, topology

I am a beginner at uv mapping and materials. So with my limited knowledge, I uv unwrapped some objects in my blender file, and then exported them to unity. While in unity, I applied some materials and saw that there were lots of distortions on the surface. After trying to do the unwrapping manually, I got the same distortions again. My question is, how should I proceed with the topology of the mesh? And there is another thing that I don't understand. In other similar meshes (with similar concave corners), when I did the unwrapping by cube projection, there weren't any distortions like this. So what is the cause of this?

[image: mesh at unity with material added]

[image: mesh with seams I manually added]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have created a second UV Map? Please pack your images and share this part of your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I'm not sure. When I add materials in blender, there are no distortions like in unity. This is my file >> https://pasteall.org/blend/2159aea2d1f743eb95aff6e7483b2995

Comment: It works fine here, I've unwrapped again with the From View option because your UV was a bit distorted but it was almost good so I'm not sure what's happening in Unity: https://zupimages.net/up/22/09/cbt4.jpg

Comment: @moonboots there are a few objects like that in the whole file, but the rest of it didn't create any problems like in here. Anyway, thank you for checking the file.